# The javascript toggle show/hide button works in small scale but not in my larger HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, class, button, toggle

Here is the concept of my content being shown/hidden. It also works. 
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/a7Lfjsgh/

It works in the small html code above. However, it does not work when I apply it to my larger HTML code. Does someone know why?

My goal is to have many list items with spans attached to the reveal answers button.

HTML:

```
<nav class="Rightbox" id="RightFrench">       
<div id="Stage1">
<h1>Stage 1</h1>
<h5> <span class="HighlightBlue">Exercise 1 - </span></h5>
<h5><button class="AnswerTitle" id="AnswersFrenchStage1Ex1">Reveal Answers</button></h5>    

<p class="Task">
  <span class="HighlightBlue">Translate the following</span>
</p>
<ul>
<li>
 <p> the passeport <textarea></textarea>
    <span class="FrenchStage1Ex1">la passeport</span>
 </p>
</li>

<li>
 <p>the passeport <textarea></textarea>
   <span class="FrenchStage1Ex1">la passeport</span>
 </p>
 </li>
</div>
</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".AnswerTitle");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
      var id = this.id.replace(/reveal/, "FrenchStage");
      var answers = document.querySelectorAll("." + id);
      for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answers[i].style.display = answers[i].style.display == "inline" ? "none" : "inline";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.Rightbox ul li p span {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem turns out to be I changed the id of the button, thinking that the javascript was not using the button id. turns out the

```
 var id = this.id.replace(/reveal/, "FrenchStage")
```

really wanted the button to have an ID containing "reveal"